# changing complete layout in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, spree

I am working on spree 1.0.0 and have been doing some research on it
for my e-commerce site.

I have already made and used some existing extensions in my app. Now,
I am working on layouts and have been trying to figure out that what
are the best possible ways for that.

My need is that I have to change the complete front end layout of my
store in comparison of what spree provides.

Some of the options from my point of view are

-> Use an extension to write all the views that overrides the templates that spree provides,

-> Use Deface to override views (which would be hectic as I have to change approx everything on almost every page)

-> Use mixed functionality of the above options.

or is there another way to do this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You are likely to have a new issue soon: to tell your new controller to use your new spree_application layout.

The spree google group indicates that you can use inheritance to use the main application everywhere: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/spree-user/mB02WqMnCnw%5B1-25%5D

However, I still haven't figured out how to solve the routing for those controllers.

Comment: Wise advice. Let me emphasis it for future generations: if you override the Spree layout with your own layout, don't forget to use `main_app` to reference your application paths. For example, `main_app.some_app_specific_path`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by overriding the `app/views/layouts/spree_application.html.erb` by placing an identically named file inside your application's `app/views` directory.